# Using waitForDuration() in spriteKit swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I wanted to wait 2 seconds between generation nodes. So I wrote this code:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    let releaseNodes = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(self.generateNode),         SKAction.waitForDuration(2)])

    self.runAction(releaseNodes)

}
```

But it doesn't work. It's generating nodes as crazy. (like 20 in seconds). How can I handle with it? Can anyone help me, please?

Edit: Here is the self.generateNode block

```
func generateNode(){

    var node: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "node")

    fish.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(-0.5),y:CGFloat(-0.2))        
    fish.position = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(10),y:CGFloat(30))

    var move = SKAction.rotateToAngle(CGFloat(3.14), duration: NSTimeInterval(1))
    var remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    var seq = SKAction.sequence([move, remove])      

    node.runAction(seq)

    self.addChild(node)    

}
```

Comment: post the self.generateNode block code

Comment: Instead of 3.14, use `M_PI` as a constant.

Comment: You shouldn't place the generateNode function in update(). You should create an SKAction that consists of a sequence with waitForDuration and generateNode and have the action repeatActionForever.

Answer (score 1):

From apple documentation on the function SKScene.Update()

`Performs any scene-specific updates that need to occur before scene actions are evaluated.`

So if within update() you're indiscriminately running actions, it will loop indefinitely creating nodes and attempting to run actions.

You should choose a better place to create your scene content. Maybe after viewDidLayoutSubviews()? or, at least in response to some action within your scene.

Edit:
It looks like you want to create content, have it move then remove it from the scene. You might be better off just creating a few sprites, saving a reference to them then having them appear, move and disappear whenever you need it. That would be safer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It sounds logical. Unfortunately, I'm working with swift, spriteKit and XCode about two days and I really dont know how I should do it. :(

Comment: If you can give me a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish I may be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd better get rid of using `update:` method and do everything with using `SKAction`s:

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)skView {
    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:2.];
    SKAction *generateNode = [SKAction runBlock:^{ 
        [self generateNode];
    }];
    [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:
        [SKAction sequence:@[wait, generateNode]]]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    static var previousTime = 0.0
    if (currentTime - previousTime) > 2.0 {
        let releaseNodes = SKAction.runBlock(self.generateNode)
        self.runAction(releaseNodes)
    }
    previousTime = currentTime
}
```

`update(currentTime:)` gives you the timestamp of the current frame. Don't forget to use that property.

Also, the last `waitForDuration:` action won't have a visible effect in your original code.