# What does a completion handler look like in Xamarin/C++ for SKAction.WaitForDuration?

Tags: c++, xamarin, sprite-kit

I am trying to implement a Wait function in my Xamarin SpriteKit game. I want to have the player do a victory animation before waiting, then loading the next level of the game. So far it implementation of Wait hasn't had any effect.

At first I just called the player animation, then the Wait action, then built the new level, however the Wait didn't work:

```
SKAction Waiting = SKAction.WaitforDuration (2);
SKAction Victory;
var textures = Enumerable.Range (1,20).Select (
(i) => SKTexture.FromImageNamed (String.Format (player_victory_{0}", i))).ToArray ();
Victory = SKAction.RepeatAction (SKAction.AnimateWithTextures (textures, 0.04),1);
SelectedNode.RunAction (Victory);
SelectedNode.RunAction (Waiting);
BuildStage (Stage); //load new level
```

I then tried to stack the wait into a sequence (again, it doesn't wait):

```
SKAction Waiting = SKAction.WaitforDuration (2);
SKAction Victory;
int Stage;

var textures = Enumerable.Range (1,20).Select (
(i) => SKTexture.FromImageNamed (String.Format (player_victory_{0}", i))).ToArray ();

Victory = SKAction.RepeatAction (SKAction.AnimateWithTextures (textures, 0.04),1);

Sequence = SKAction.Sequence (new SKAction [] {Victory,Waiting});

public void CheckGoal (SKSpriteNote SelectedNode)
{
//extra code that confirms Goal
SelectedNode.RunAction (Sequence);
Stage = Stage + 1;
RemoveAllChildren();
BuildStage (Stage);
```

I read that just because the code is sequential, it doesn't mean it will wait until the previous call has finished, and I needed a completion handler.

I found this [similar question/answer on SO for Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969260/using-waitforduration-in-spritekit-swift), however I am not proficient enough to convert that into a Xamarin/C++ solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to my original question, but I do have a work around in place for now which is doing the job. I'm still keen to learn the SKAction completion code, but for now this will have to do.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks

public void CheckGoal (SKSpriteNote SelectedNode)
{
//extra code that confirms Goal
SelectedNode.RunAction (Victory); //animation plays for .8 seconds
await Task.Delay (1500); //waits here for 1.5 seconds, allowing animation to play plus some buffer time
Stage = Stage + 1;
RemoveAllChildren();
BuildStage (Stage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the Xamarin or C++ syntax you are using but this should get you close. You were very close with the sequence, but you need to build what you want it to do at the end into the sequence. A runBlock should do the trick for you.

```
SKAction customBlock = SKAction.runBlock({
            Stage = Stage + 1
            RemoveAllChildren()
            BuildStage (Stage)
        })

Sequence = SKAction.Sequence (new SKAction [] {Victory,Waiting, customBlock});

public void CheckGoal (SKSpriteNote SelectedNode)
{
    //extra code that confirms Goal
    SelectedNode.RunAction (Sequence);

}
```

Hopefully that made sense and is useful.